# SwiftUI - Picker has two sets of init - what are the second set for? and how do i get selected item?

Tags: swiftui, picker

Im going through SwiftUI Controls in detail and writing example code for each init.

Theres two sets of inits for Picker.

One where you fill your list from an array etc. and what you pick goes into selection: binding.

But whats the second set of inits for?
Theyre under section 'Creating a picker for a collection'
I can fill the array from a collection using both these inits ok

But how do you get the selected item using the 2nd set of inits?
The selection: param is no longer a binding to an ivar but a Keypath to fill the list.
My question is how do I get the selected item using the 2nd set of inits.

See inits here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/picker

For Picker there are 6 inits.

- 3 under 'Creating a picker'

  - these are ok. I fill the list from an array for example and store the selected item in a single result specified by the selection: param. It binds the result to one ivar.
- There are also 3 inits under 'Creating a picker for a collection'

I got this to display the items from a collection
e.g. I modified the example code in the apple docs. The code in the docs doesn't compile so apple may be missing stuff.

```
    import SwiftUI

    enum Thickness: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
       case thin
       case regular
       case thick
    
        var id: String { rawValue }

    }

    //to use in ist must be Hashable
    struct Border: Identifiable  {
        var color: Color
        var thickness: Thickness
    
        //Identifiable > Hashable > id > String
        //var id: String { return "\(color.hashValue)" }
    
        let id = UUID()
    }
    extension Color{
        func colorName() -> String{
            if self == Color.black{
                 return "black"
            }
            else if self == Color.red{
                return "red"
            }
            else{
               return "UNHANDLED"
            }
        }
    }



    struct CLCPickers_selection_FromCollection_View: View {
    
    @State private var selectedObjectBorders = [
        Border(color: .black, thickness: .thin),
        Border(color: .red, thickness: .thick)
    ]
    

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            //------------------------------------------------------------------
            Picker(
                "Border Thickness",
                sources: $selectedObjectBorders,
                selection: \.thickness
            ) {
                //------------------------------------------------------------------
                //I added
                //id: \.self
                //Picker: the selection "thin" is invalid and does not have an associated tag, this will give undefined results.
                //------------------------------------------------------------------
                ForEach(Thickness.allCases,
                        id: \.self)
                { thickness in
                    Text(thickness.rawValue)
                }
            }

            //------------------------------------------------------------------
            Divider()
            //------------------------------------------------------------------
            //This just lists the colors in the arrays of Border
            
            //QUESTION - how do I find out the currenly selected one?
            //normaly selection: in the picker would be bound to the picked item
            //but for this init selection: is a keypath
            //selection: \.thickness
            //so I can fill the Picker list using the keypath into the Border array.
            //BUT HOW DO I FIND OUT THE CURRENTLY SELECTED ITEM?
            //theres no binding? 
            //is there a .selectedItem property some where?
            
            List(selectedObjectBorders) {
                Text("\($0.color.colorName())")
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Question was answered but poster removed it for some reason.

answer: this picker init which set the thinkness ivar of EVERY Border object in the collection.

To see the change I should have displayed the result to show thickness.rawvalue to see the change in every Border object

```
    List(selectedObjectBorders) { border in
        HStack{
            Text("\(border.color.colorName())")
            Text("\(border.thickness.rawValue)") //<<- will change when you select an item. All will match.
    }
}
```